# Junit5 Intellij IDEA assertsThrows() throws noSuchMethodError

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I'm trying to run test in Junit5 which should catch an exception from method. It catches NoSuchMethodError instead of excepted exception.

Method:

```
public void thisMethodShouldThrowException() throws IllegalArgumentException {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Test method:

```
@Test
void thisMethodShouldThrowException() throws IllegalArgumentException {
    DBProperties dbProperties = DBProperties.getInstance();
    Assertions.assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class,
        ()->dbProperties.thisMethodShouldThrowException());
}
```

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.3.0-alpha4'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.11'
    testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.0.0'
    testCompile group: 'org.junit.platform', name: 'junit-platform-launcher', version: '1.0.0'
    testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-engine', version: '5.0.0'
    testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-params', version: '5.0.0'
    testCompile("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:4.12.0")
}
```

Stack trace:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Unexpected exception type thrown ==> 
Expected :<java.lang.IllegalArgumentException> 
Actual   :<java.lang.NoSuchMethodError>
<Click to see difference>


at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:59)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:38)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows(Assertions.java:1108)
at pl.javamill.bnbahistory.Controller.DBPropertiesTest.thisMethodShouldThrowException(DBPropertiesTest.java:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:389)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:163)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:110)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:83)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$null$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$null$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: pl.javamill.bnbahistory.Controller.DBProperties.thisMethodShouldThrowException()V
at pl.javamill.bnbahistory.Controller.DBPropertiesTest.lambda$thisMethodShouldThrowException$1(DBPropertiesTest.java:24)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertThrows.assertThrows(AssertThrows.java:50)
... 54 more
```

Intellij Idea version is 2018.2
I tried lastest version of Junit5 also.
I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Can you help me?

Comment: Could you please post the stacktrace of the error you are getting?

Comment: Could be a version issue. Have you tried the latest releases of Jupiter, Vintage and platform? They all should end x.2.0

Comment: Also, make sure you're using a recent version of IntelliJ, at least 2017.3.

Comment: You might want to create a public repo so that we can actually run your example. The problem might be in the project structure or some (missing) dependency which cannot be seen from the code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error using `junit-jupiter-api 5.3.2`. A quick research showed the following:

```
  import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;
  import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
  import org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable;
  import org.junit.jupiter.api.function.ThrowingSupplier;

  @Test
  public void testVoidMethod() {
    // works
    Executable supplier = () -> crash();
    assertThrows(NullPointerException.class, supplier);
  }

  @Test
  public void testMethodWithReturnTypeCalledByExecutable() {
    // works
    Executable supplier = () -> wrong();
    assertThrows(NullPointerException.class, supplier);
  }

  @Test
  public void testMethodWithReturnType() {
    // fails
    assertThrows(NullPointerException.class, () -> wrong());
  }

  @Test
  public void testMethodWithReturnTypeCalledByThrowingSupplier() {
    // fails
    ThrowingSupplier<?> supplier = () -> wrong();
    assertThrows(NullPointerException.class, supplier);
  }

  public void crash() {
    throw new NullPointerException();
  }

  public Object wrong() {
    throw new NullPointerException();
  }
```

Using `assertThrows` with a `ThrowingSupplier` raises a `NoSuchMethodError`.

I update to `junit-jupiter-api 5.4.0`. The API changed. There is no method `assertThrows` with a `ThrowingSupplier` as parameter anymore. Only the ones taking an `Executable` remained. But there are some new methods taking a `ThrowingSupplier` named `assertDoesNotThrow`.

Finally I updated to `junit-jupiter-api 5.5.2`.

The [5.4 Release Notes](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.4.0/release-notes/index.html#bug-fixes-7) mention a bugfix of a similar case. However this is not an explanation for the `NoSuchMethodError`.

**UPDATE:**

The `NoSuchMethodError` is thrown if I run the JUnit tests via Eclipse's JUnit plugin. It uses `org.junit.jupiter.api_5.1.0.v20180327-1502.jar` whereas in the `pom.xml` JUnit 5.3.2 was specified. Running the tests with maven at JUnit 5.3.2 succeeds.

This was my case using Eclipse. I don't have IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking up this same problem with something I was coding, and I fixed my issue by putting the test method into curly braces like so:

```
Assertions.assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class,
        () -> {dbProperties.thisMethodShouldThrowException();} );
```

Comment: Yes this works because _by putting the test method into curly braces_ you changed the type of the lambda from  `ThrowingSupplier`  to `Executable` as the lambda body got  [void-compatible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2)